# subsetting affects .view(np.float64) behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, casting, subset

I'm trying to use some sklearn estimators for classifications on the coefficients of some fast fourier transform (technically Discrete Fourier Transform). I obtain a numpy array X_c as output of np.fft.fft(X) and I want to transform it into a real numpy array X_r, with each (complex) column of the original X_c transformed into two (real/float) columns in X_r, i.e the shape goes from (r, c) to (r, 2c). So I use .view(np.float64). and it works at first.

The problem is that if I first decide to keep only some coefficients of the original complex array with X_c2 = X_c[:, range(3)] and then to do the same thing as before instead of having the number of columns doubled, I obtain the number of ranks doubled (the imaginary part of each element is put in a new row below the original).

I really don't understand why this happens.

To make myself clearer, here is a toy example:

```
import numpy as np

# I create a complex array
X_c = np.arange(8, dtype = np.complex128).reshape(2, 4)
print(X_c.shape) # -> (2, 4)

# I use .view to transform it into something real and it works
# the way I want it.
X_r = X_c.view(np.float64)
print(X_r.shape) # -> (2, 8)

# Now I subset the array.
indices_coef = range(3)
X_c2 = X_c[:, indices_coef]
print(X_c2.shape) # -> (2, 3)
X_r2 = X_c2.view(np.float64)

# In the next line I obtain (4, 3), when I was expecting (2, 6)...
print(X_r2.shape) # -> (4, 3)
```

Does anyone see a reason for this difference of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a warning:

```
In [5]: X_c2 = X_c[:,range(3)]
In [6]: X_c2
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  2.+0.j],
       [ 4.+0.j,  5.+0.j,  6.+0.j]])
In [7]: X_c2.view(np.float64)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: Changing the shape of non-C contiguous array by
descriptor assignment is deprecated. To maintain
the Fortran contiguity of a multidimensional Fortran
array, use 'a.T.view(...).T' instead
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])


In [12]: X_c2.strides
Out[12]: (16, 32)
In [13]: X_c2.flags
Out[13]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
```

So this copy (or is a view?) is Fortran order.  The recommended `X_c2.T.view(float).T` produces the same 4x3 array without the warning.

As your first view shows, a complex array has the same data layout as twice the number of floats.

I've seen funny shape behavior when trying to `view` a structured array.  I'm wondering the `complex` dtype is behaving much like a `dtype('f8,f8')` array.

---

If I change your `X_c2` so it is a copy, I get the expected behavior

```
In [19]: X_c3 = X_c[:,range(3)].copy()
In [20]: X_c3.flags
Out[20]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
In [21]: X_c3.strides
Out[21]: (48, 16)
In [22]: X_c3.view(float)
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  6.,  0.]])
```

That's reassuring.  But I'm puzzled as to why the `[:, range(3)]` indexing creates a F order view.  That should be advance indexing.

And indeed, a true slice does not allow this view

```
In [28]: X_c[:,:3].view(np.float64)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

So the range indexing has created some sort of hybrid object.

Comment: Looks like the advanced indexing docs do address this: [The memory layout of an advanced indexing result is optimized for each indexing operation and no particular memory order can be assumed.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#detailed-notes)

Comment: If you want to guarantee a particular memory order for the result, `numpy.asarray(result, order='C')` would do the job. `numpy.array(result, order='C', copy='False')` also works; it's slightly wordier, but slightly more consistent with the docs.

Comment: There's also `numpy.ascontiguousarray(result)`, which guarantees a C contiguous array (Fortran contiguous doesn't count).

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I'm quite new to python so I don't really understand how this memory allocation works and what is this .copy() command, but now it works. I also wasn't aware of these contiguous issue. I had seen the warning but following the instructions didn't seem to change my problem so I left my code as I posted it.

Comment: @GWa (@user2357112), I just moved the mystery a bit deeper.  I still don't know why it changed the order to do this indexing.  It seems buggy to me.  Advanced indexing with the first dimension doesn't do this, e.g. `arr[[0],[1]], range(3)]`.